# For estimating the difference between two population means, how do you decide which specific case (out of the four) to apply?

Tags: statistics

So there are the four cases: independent- unknown variance equal/unequal, independent-known variance, and dependent populations. But I'm not sure how to decide whether the variance is equal or unequal if the variance is unknown (the problem doesn't state whether or not the variance is equal or not).

The problem is:

The federal government awarded grants to the agricultural departments of 9 universities to test the yield capabilities of two new varieties of wheat. Each variety was planted on a plot of equal area at each university, and the yields, in kilograms per plot, were recorded as follows:

[image]

In order to find a 95% confidence interval for the mean difference between the yields of the two varieties, assuming the differences of yields to be approximately normally distributed, which of the four cases is valid?

Comment: Assuming that the individual Varities are independent and follow a Normal Distribution, You can carry out an F test to test the hypothesis that they have equal variance and go ahead with the appropriate test (equal or unequal variance depending upon the outcome of F test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question of equal or unequal variance is irrelevant, because the correct test in this case is a paired test.  The reason is because each university plants both varieties, so the effect of variable growth conditions from one university to another is controlled for by taking the difference of yields.  Analogously, the confidence interval you must construct is for the mean difference, which will have only one standard error overall, not one for each variety.